# Conjugation in S4 preserves cycle structure

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

For proving the klein four group being a normal subgroup of the alternating group A4, there is the remark that conjugation in S4 preserves the cycle structure. What does that mean? What is meant with cycle structure in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles. For instance
$$\sigma=(1\,7\,3)(4\,10)(2\,11\,6\,5\,12)(8\,9)$$
is a permutation in $S_{12}$ with two $2$-cycles, one $3$-cycle
and one $5$-cycle. Any conjugate of $\sigma$ in $S_{12}$ will
also have two $2$-cycles, one $3$-cycle
and one $5$-cycle. The *cycle structure* is just this census of
the cycles of the permutation by their lengths. So basically it's
a list of numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ where $a_j$ is the number of $j$-cycles
the permutation has.

Comment: Very clear, thank you!